# Error while retrieving data from a MySQL DB from Oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle

One of our clients is trying to connect from their Oracle DB and retrieve information from our MySQL DB. They get the following error:

```
[MySQL][ODBC 5.2(a) Driver]MySQL server has gone away {HY000,NativeErr = 2006}
...
ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:
[MySQL][ODBC 5.2(a) Driver][mysqld-5.6.34-log]Invalid descriptor index {07009,NativeErr = 9}
```

Based on different suggestions online (here and other forums) our MySQL settings are as follows:

```
wait_timeout : 28800 
max_allowed_packet : 134217728
innodb_log_file_size : 134217728
```

Please let me know if we are missing something that we should be looking for from our side. At this point we don't know where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, it looks like the UnixODBC driver manager is too old for the ODBC driver. Upgrading UnixODBC should help with this.

Comment: yes we found this online https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?37,659621,659961 - however the client told us that their drivers are up to date

Comment: I found that thread too. Could the client confirm the version?

Comment: This is what the clients have: ```mysql-connector-odbc-5.2.7-1.el7.x86_64
unixODBC-2.3.1-14.0.1.el7.x86_64```